# Send multipart/form-data files with angular using $http

Tags: angularjs, http, file-upload, http-headers, multipartform-data

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but I can't get this to work:

I want to upload a file from input to a server in multipart/form-data

I've tried two approaches. First:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': undefined
},
```

Which results in e.g. for an image

```
Content-Type:image/png
```

while it should be multipart/form-data

and the other:

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': multipart/form-data
},
```

But this asks for a boundry header, which I believe should not be manually inserted...

What is a clean way to solve this problem? 
I've read that you can do

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8';
```

But I don't want all my posts to be multipart/form-data. The default should be JSON

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Take a look at the FormData object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just confirmed and IE 9 must no longer be supported for this project, so this is perfect for me! Thx!

Comment: This works but why does the `Content-Type`has to be set to `undefined` ?

Comment: @meucaa The code snippet looks similar to what's on this blog post which states: "By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request." - https://www.uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs/

Comment: instead of file if i have base64(blob) how can i upload ? @jstuartmilne

Comment: I am working with an ASP.NET Web API backend, and this is exactly what was needed!  I didn't need the `transformRequest` bit, however.  Thank you!

Answer (score 38):

Here's an updated answer for Angular 4 & 5. TransformRequest and angular.identity were dropped. I've also included the ability to combine files with JSON data in one request.

Angular 5 Solution:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

uploadFileToUrl(files, restObj, uploadUrl): Promise<any> {
  // Note that setting a content-type header
  // for mutlipart forms breaks some built in
  // request parsers like multer in express.
  const options = {} as any; // Set any options you like
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Append files to the virtual form.
  for (const file of files) {
    formData.append(file.name, file)
  }

  // Optional, append other kev:val rest data to the form.
  Object.keys(restObj).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, restObj[key]);
  });

  // Send it.
  return this.httpClient.post(uploadUrl, formData, options)
    .toPromise()
    .catch((e) => {
      // handle me
    });
}
```

Angular 4 Solution:

```
// Note that these imports below are deprecated in Angular 5
import {Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

uploadFileToUrl(files, restObj, uploadUrl): Promise<any> {
  // Note that setting a content-type header
  // for mutlipart forms breaks some built in
  // request parsers like multer in express.
  const options = new RequestOptions();
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Append files to the virtual form.
  for (const file of files) {
    formData.append(file.name, file)
  }

  // Optional, append other kev:val rest data to the form.
  Object.keys(restObj).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, restObj[key]);
  });

  // Send it.
  return this.http.post(uploadUrl, formData, options)
    .toPromise()
    .catch((e) => {
      // handle me
    });
}
```

Comment: then the problem is IE 11

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 6, you can do this:

In your service file:

```
 function_name(data) {
    const url = `the_URL`;
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append('url', data);   // "url" as the key and "data" as value
    return this.http.post(url, input).pipe(map((resp: any) => resp));
  }
```

In component.ts file:
in any function say xyz,

```
xyz(){
this.Your_service_alias.function_name(data).subscribe(d => {   // "data" can be your file or image in base64 or other encoding
      console.log(d);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Angular 13 (~13.0.0)** isn't need to specify **Content-Type** of request.

some.service.ts:

```
public sendFiles(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();

    data.files.forEach((file: File) => {
      formData.append('files', file);
    });
    
    const url: string = <YOUR_API_URL>;

    return this.http.post<any>(url, formData);
}
```

- Set **Content-Type** field to the following values ​​will result in error:

  - 'file'
  - undefined (can't with strict mode active)
  - 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 2):

**In angular 9**,
Before  tried 'Content-Type': undefined, but it is not worked for me
then
I tried the below  code  and It works like charms for a file object

```
const request = this.http.post(url, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'file'
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not **Set**, **Reset** or **Update** the built in FormData's **Content-Type**. It will be solved. In **Angular 7** it works.

Though there was an **Auth-Interceptor** But I did not let it set, change or reset my **Content-Type** header of my post request. Let it be what it is and the problem is solved.

[Here is my auth interceptor image where I by passed my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcirH.png)