# How should I format an Angular POST to a WebAPI endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send an image from an Angular app to the endpoint. However, I get the following exception from the backend : Http failure response for http://localhost:[port]/api/sendimage: 415 Unsupported Media Type

My Angular code is the following :

```
  const data = receivedImage;
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' // Set the content type to JSON
  });

  this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:[port]/api/sendimage', data, { headers })
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log('Response from server:', response);
      // Handle response as needed
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Handle error
    }
  );
```

And my endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/sendimage")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadImage()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
...process the image
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to upload an image but you are setting the post to a JSON format? That seems incorrect to me. Check this [related, possibly duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722093/send-multipart-form-data-files-with-angular-using-http)

Comment: you must set the port. `[port`] is just a string here, not a placeholder. You can see it in the error message, it's still there as `[port]` instead of the value of the port.

Comment: You may want to use FormData for this... it'll set the headers automatically and stream the file... you can then bind to IFile on backend.  Something like: let form = document.getElementById('yourFormID')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);   this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:[port]/api/sendimage', formData)